# Unity music transfer between scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The game I am creating is a tutorial of Brackeys called Sunnyland with a few twists and challenges for myself. One particular problem I'm facing is the music functionality. There are a few scenes for menus, each can be accessed from the main menu, a scene for the level and a winning scene after you finish it.

I want one audio file to play in the menu scenes, one for the level and one for the ending.
So far, I have solved the issue of changing scenes without stopping the audio but every time I come back to the main menu, the audio plays again while the previous record is not stopping. Then, when I press the "Start" button to play the level, it keeps playing along with the level soundtrack. And of course, it keeps playing on the winning scene.

So to summarize: my problems right now are:

1. audio playing multiple times in the menu sections
2. menu audio goes into the level  and winning scenes (only if multiple records were activated)
   Here is the code I'm using to play the audio through the menu scenes:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
```

```
public class MusicControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    private AudioSource music;

    private void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
        music = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    public void PlayMusic()
    {
        if (music.isPlaying) return;
        {
            music.Play();
        }
    }

    public void StopMusic()
    {
        music.Stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject)` In the Awake() function of the music GameObject.
`DontDestroyOnLoad()` keeps objects between scenes and doesn't destroy the object.
And just stop the menu audio when you go into another scene?